# Restarting SystemUI using am startservice

Tags: android, android-service, adb

I have been trying to restart SytemUI using these in my app,but it is not working,am on Android 4.0.4.Any help?

> am startservice -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService

It works in adb shell,but not in my app or in terminal on android.

Code I am using in my app:

```
Process mSuProcess; mSuProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); 

DataOutputStream mSuDataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(mSuProcess.getOutputStream()); 

mSuDataOutputStream.writeBytes("am startservice -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService\n");
```

Comment: `adb shell` in that case probably working as root. Is that a rooted phone you are trying on?

Comment: Yes,it is rooted.And I am running 'su',something like  Process mSuProcess;
    mSuProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

Comment: what happens if you run shell instead of su?

Comment: how to run it?mSu=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb");?

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation.I don't have it:/.

Comment: Do you know the reason of this behaviour? I'm curious. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run shell instead of su, like;

```
Process mSuProcess;  mSuProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh");
```

Answer (score 10):

After a lot of searching on the internet, I managed to get the System Bar to appear in a 4.2 device using:

```
am startservice --user 0 -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService
```

Alternatively some people have used the -a (instead of -n) option, though this was causing a error or my device:

Error: Not found; no service started.

Comment: This works nicely. I noticed that when hiding the SystemUI, the desktop image disappears as well, which is fine. But when showing the SystemUI again the desktop image does not reappear with until reboot. Anyone perhaps know of a way to refresh or reload it without needing to reboot?

Comment: Wow Thank you This is working. Do you know why it's not working on my Kitkat device (custom AOSP ROM) without the --user 0 ?